# Recognition Visa and Mastercard with Card.IO

Tags: ios, card.io, mastercard

In my project I need to recognize visa and mastercard like an the picture and I found this type in CardIOCreditCardType, but in practice it doesn't work for Card.io SDK. May be this SDK must have some special configuration for this recognition?[image: Bank card example]

Comment: Dave from card.io here. Are you trying to scan actual, traditionally formatted VISA and MasterCard cards with embossed numbers? The scan should succeed for the majority of such cards.

Comment: @dave-goldman
Could you try to test your simple application on image in my question? I have three cards - one Mastercard and two Visas, with formatted numbers and without it and simple application doesn't work.

Comment: The image above includes an invalid card number. The prefix `1234` does not correspond to any card type. (Also, card.io is NOT designed to scan images on a computer screen.)

Comment: I tested simple app on these cards. It doesn't work
https://pp.vk.me/c625521/v625521524/6f567/RH1eSeE0Tlg.jpg

Comment: it's not obvious to me why card.io failed to scan those cards; their numbers look pretty distinct to me (even the card whose numbers do not appear to be embossed).

Comment: Can i use someone debug mode maybe?